# Django checkboxes not saving to database: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-views, django-templates

Value of checkbox when clicked is not saved in database Django.

I am creating a website to track the progress of printing a book. The data is not being saved in the database and i don't know why. I have a table called Book which is working perfectly and another table called Progress which has the progress steps.
In my template, I want to have the progress steps as checkboxes and the user clicks on the checkbox when that step is done (like how a to-do list works for example)
My problem is that when I click on the checkbox , nothing happens.

**Models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    BookName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Author=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CopiesNum=models.IntegerField()
    PartsNum=models.IntegerField()
    CoverType=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PaperType=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    BookSize=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    BookCompletion=models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Progress(models.Model):
    BookID=models.ForeignKey(to=Book,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='BookID')
    BookName=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    ISBNsent=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ISBN_sentDate=models.DateField(null=True)
    ISBNdelivered=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ISBN_deliveredDate=models.DateField(null=True)
    DepositNum=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    ISBN=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

**Template:** (note I just tried on the first checkbox)

```
div class="container " dir="rtl">
        <div class="section">
          <div class="columns is-3 ">
        <!--############## FIRST COLUMN CARD ##############-->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <header class="card-header is-info">
                      <p class="card-header-title is-centered">
                        رقم الايداع
                      </p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card-content" dir="rtl">
                      <form action="{%url 'tracker:ISBN_check' book_page.id }" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="columns is-mobile">
                            <div class="content column is-5">
                              <label class="checkbox" dir="rtl">
                                **<input type="checkbox" name="ISBNsent" id="ISBNsent" value="True" onclick="this.form.submit({book_id:book_page.book_id})">**
                                تم التسليم
                              </label>
                              </div>
                            
                      
                            <div class="content column ">
                              <label class="date" dir="rtl">بتاريخ
                                <input type="date" name="ISBN_sentDate" id="ISBN_sentDate" disabled>
                            </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="columns is-mobile">
                          <div class="content column is-5">
                              <label class="checkbox" dir="rtl">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ISBNdelivered" id="ISBNdelivered">
                                تم الاستلام 
                              </label>
                            </div>
                      
                            <div class="content column">
                              <label class="date" dir="rtl">بتاريخ
                                <input type="date" name="ISBN_deliveredDate" id="ISBN_deliveredDate" disabled>
                              </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="content">
                              <input class="input pb-2" type="text" placeholder=" رقم الايداع">
                            </div>
                      
                            <div class="content">
                              <input class="input pb-2" type="text" placeholder="الترقيم الدولي">
                            </div>
                      
                    </div>
                    <footer class="card-footer">
                      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Done</a>
                    </footer>
                  </form>
            </div>
            </div>
  
         
           
          
             <!--############## END FIRST CARD ##############-->
```

**views.py**

```
def bookSteps(request,book_id):
   book_page = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
   
   return render(request, 'tracker/Book.html', {'book_page': book_page})
def ISBN_check(request,book_id):
   book_page = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
   print('HELLO HELLO')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      print('Request method is:', request.method)
      # Get the form data
      data = request.POST
      # Check if the ISBNsent checkbox is checked
      #if request.POST.get("ISBNsent"):
      if data['ISBNsent']:
         progress=Progress(
         ISBNsent=True,
         ISBN_sentDate=timezone.now()) 
         return render(request,'tracker/success.html') 
      # Check if the ISBNdelivered checkbox is checked
      if data['ISBNdelivered']:
         # Set the delivered date to the current date
         progress=Progress(
         ISBNdelivered=True,
         ISBN_deliveredDate=timezone.now())

      # Get the Progress object with the specified book_id
      progress.book=book_page
      
      # Save the progress
      progress.save()

   return render(request, 'tracker/Book.html', {'book_page': book_page})
```

(**Note:** the print statements were for debugging, the first hello print statements gets printed when i refresh the page but when i click the checkbox nothing happens and the other print statement never got printed)

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path("", views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('', views.login ,name="login"),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('book/', views.book, name="book"),
    path('add/', views.AddBook, name="AddBook"),
    path('dashboard/book/<int:book_id>', views.bookSteps, name="bookSteps"),
    path('dashboard/book/<int:book_id>', views.ISBN_check, name="ISBN_check"),  
]
```

**EDIT:** added url , edited views and form action

Answer (score 1):

Your form `action` is malformatted:

```html
action="{% url 'tracker:bookSteps'                    }" // Change this
action="{% url 'tracker:bookSteps' book_page.book_id %}" // to this
```

`this.form.submit()` also does not take any parameters:

```html
onclick="this.form.submit({book_id: book_page.book_id})" // Change this
onclick="this.form.submit()"                             // to this
```

Comment: Thank you so much , when I changed that I am getting a Page not found error , so I think the main problem of submitting the data is solved, but I am getting a urlpatterns problem. Do you have an idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Edit your question to show your urls.py.

Comment: I did the following edit: added url.py , edited views function and form action

Comment: You're still missing the `%` in `%}`.

Comment: sorry that was just in the edit here but in my code the % is there

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that. Can you share a repro project on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly that, you don't save the records to the database, you should use:

```
if data['ISBNsent']:
    progress = Progress(
        ISBNsent=True,
        ISBN_sentDate=timezone.now(),
        book=book_page,
    )
    progress.save()
```

or:

```
if data['ISBNsent']:
    progress = Progress.objects.create(
        ISBNsent=True,
        ISBN_sentDate=timezone.now(),
        book=book_page,
    )
```

Your check should however check if `'ISBNsent'` is an element of `request.POST`, since a checkbox is not sent if not checked, so:

```
if 'ISBNsent' in data:
    progress = Progress.objects.create(
        ISBNsent=True, ISBN_sentDate=timezone.now()
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

Comment: Thank you for taking out of your time. There is a progress.save() at the end of the view function. And as i mentioned in the question when i tried to debug , the print statement after the if statement of the POST request did not get printed that means that it does not reach that.